# Android activity views changes their display order to opposite after onPause-onResume

Tags: android, android-layout, android-lifecycle

My problem is partially similar to [EditText in listview in opposite order onresume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9369247/edittext-in-listview-in-opposite-order-onresume)

I have the layout with 3 views:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <view
        android:id="@+id/above"
        android:layout_width="1px"
        android:layout_height="1px"
        class="com.hooliganslab.stormx.VSurfaceView"
    />

    <view
        android:id="@+id/gl_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.hooliganslab.stormx.GLNativeSurfaceView"
    />

    <view
        android:id="@+id/below"
        android:layout_width="1px"
        android:layout_height="1px"
        class="com.hooliganslab.stormx.VSurfaceView"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

When application started (onCreate-onResume) view identified as "below" lies below of view identified as gl_view, view identified as "above" lies above of view identified as gl_view.

When application reappeared after pause (onPause-onResume) views changes their display order to opposite: view identified as "above" lies below of view identified as gl_view, view identified as "below" lies above of view identified as gl_view. This order then remains steadily despite the further switching.

This behavior does not depend on the type of used layout (RelativeLayout or FrameLayout) nor wrapping views into LinearLayouts.

If I call setZOrderMediaOverlay(true) for gl_view, it always lies over both "above" and "below" views.

What should I do to create a proper and permanent order of views?

Excuse me, I probably vaguely formulated question.

android:layout_below fixes the relative position of views in the plane. But I am interested in the ordering of views in the sense of z-order.

Comment: use layout_above and layout_above in your views to fix position

Comment: Excuse me, I probably vaguely formulated question.
android:layout_above fixes the relative position of views in the plane. But I am interested in the ordering of views in the sense of z-order.

Answer (score 0):

you are not specifying any position in your `layout`. Use `layout_below` and `layout_above` to specify exact position

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<view
    android:id="@+id/above"
    android:layout_width="1px"
    android:layout_height="1px"
    class="com.hooliganslab.stormx.VSurfaceView"
/>

<view
    android:id="@+id/gl_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/above" // like this
    class="com.hooliganslab.stormx.GLNativeSurfaceView"
/>

<view
    android:id="@+id/below"
    android:layout_width="1px"
    android:layout_height="1px"
    class="com.hooliganslab.stormx.VSurfaceView"
/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Giving IDs to views will not place them relative to each other. you need to change your layout to:

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <view
        android:id="@+id/above"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        class="com.hooliganslab.stormx.VSurfaceView" />

    <view
        android:id="@+id/gl_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/above"
        class="com.hooliganslab.stormx.GLNativeSurfaceView" />

    <view
        android:layout_below="@id/gl_view"
        android:id="@+id/below"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        class="com.hooliganslab.stormx.VSurfaceView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```